# Excel Formula -> VBA: Date of each Friday of the current month

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have the current formula created by @ScottCraner which when pasted into Cell Q8 and Dragged down to Q12, populates the cells with the date of each friday this month:

Code:

```
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDEX(A:A,EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1)+1):INDEX(A:A,EOMONTH(TODAY(),0)))/(WEEKDAY(ROW(INDEX(A:A,EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1)+1):INDEX(A:A,EOMONTH(TODAY(),0))),1)=6),ROW(1:1)),"-")
```

Im trying to convert this into VBA as i understand VBA more than formulas. However was wondering if anyone here could possibly help.

It really is appreciated

Comment: `Rng.Formula = "=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDEX(A:A,EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1)+1):INDEX(A:A,EOMONTH(TODAY(),0)))/(WEEKDAY(ROW(INDEX(A:A,EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1)+1):INDEX(A:A,EOMONTH(TODAY(),0))),1)=6),ROW(1:1)),""-"")"`

Comment: The other way would be to loop through dates and then check if it is friday or not

Comment: ^^^^ Which is exactly what the formula is doing.

Comment: @SiddharthRout So basically you set the range of cells to populate with the formula text instead of having to write it to the cells manually? Makes sense, thank you for your time :)

Comment: @Jeeped: Ah! I can see you are going to get one now :D. Awesome! It is a nice mug. I have my daily tea in it.

Comment: @SiddharthRout, yeah, I'm in the home stretch now.

Comment: Hello, you might be interested on the answer mentioned here, https://stackoverflow.com/a/73252070/5724536

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This iterates the dates and puts the Fridays in Q8:Q12

```
Sub myFri()
    Dim OArr(1 To 5, 1 To 1) As Variant
    Dim k As Long
    k = 1
    Dim i As Long
    For i = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), 1) To DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date) + 1, 0)
        If Weekday(i, vbSunday) = 7 Then
            OArr(k, 1) = i
            k = k + 1
        End If
    Next i

    If k = 5 Then OArr(k, 1) = "-"

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("Q8:Q12").Value = OArr
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("Q8:Q12").NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
End Sub
```

Comment: You can use `DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date) + 1, 0)` to get the EOM.

Comment: Yeah, apparently day 0 of next month is the last day of this month.

Comment: so what do you think of the formula? that is one of mine from another question by this OP.

Comment: I used to use something similar with sumproduct. That's how I learned that today()/7+1 was the weekday according to vbsunday. It's a perfectly valid method; too bad the op chose to keep the credit for its construction.

Comment: Thank you @ScottCraner I really appreciate all youve done for me so far. Youve been a great help in all the questions ive asked regarding my project so far. Im going to use this for the date iteration now as it gives me a lot more flexibility when it comes to changes later on, like defining the day to work this out from. Thanks again :)

Comment: ++ Nice one Scott :)

Answer (score 4):

Try this quick UDF.

```
Function listWeekday(dt As Long, ndx As Long, _
                     Optional wd As Long = 6)
    listWeekday = 7 - Weekday(DateSerial(Year(dt), Month(dt), 0), wd) + _
                  DateSerial(Year(dt), Month(dt), 1) + _
                  (ndx - 1) * 7
    If Month(dt) <> Month(listWeekday) Then _
        listWeekday = CVErr(xlErrNA)

End Function

'usage for Fridays in current month
=listWeekday(today(), row(1:1))
'usage for Sundays in current month
=listWeekday(today(), row(1:1), 1)
'usage for Wednesdays in current month
=listWeekday(today(), row(1:1), 4)
```

Comment: This also works as intended, thank you for your time :) Im going to be using @ScottCraner 's vba script as i can personally undestand it a little easier. Thank you

Comment: ++ nice lil compact function :)