# How to determine the date of previous Friday?

Tags: vba, outlook

I'd like to create an email with an attachment where there is a date in the name of the file.

I'd be composing this email generally Monday for a file name that's dated for the previous Friday.

File name to be attached: 20210205 - XYZ.pdf

Here's the code I have so far:

```
Sub WMSCL()
        
    LastFridayDate = Date - Weekday(Date, vbSaturday)
    
    Dim oMsg As Outlook.MailItem
    
    Set oMsg = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    With oMsg
    
        .To =
        .CC = 
        .Subject = 
        .Attachments.Add "C:\filepath\LastFriday & "- XYZ.pdf"
        .HTMLBody = 
        .Display
        
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello, you might be interested on the answer mentioned here, https://stackoverflow.com/a/73252070/5724536

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just needed to format the date so it is in the correct date format as your file path and concatenate the date to the file path correctly.

```
Sub WMSCL()
    Dim lastFridayDate As Variant
    Dim filePath As String
    Dim oMsg As Outlook.MailItem

    Set oMsg = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    lastFridayDate = Date - Weekday(Date, vbSaturday)
    lastFridayDate = Format(lastFridayDate, "yyyymmdd")
    filePath = "C:\filepath\"
    filePath = filePath & lastFridayDate & " - XYZ.pdf"

    With oMsg
        .To =
        .CC =
        .Subject =
        .Attachments.Add filePath
        .HTMLBody =
        .Display
    End With
    'Cleanup
    Set oMsg = Nothing
End Sub
```